# Django-Summernote: How do I override the admin form textareas with the Summernote widget?

Tags: django, summernote

I'm new to Django and trying to figure out how to override all of my textarea fields in my Admin Model Forms.  I saw this in the django-summernote docs:

```
from django_summernote.admin import SummernoteModelAdmin

# Apply summernote to all TextField in model.
class SomeModelAdmin(SummernoteModelAdmin):  # instead of ModelAdmin
    ...
```

But I'm not sure what should replace the ellipses. Is there a way to do this for all textareas in Admin at once or does this need to be applied to each Model?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, `ellipses` means custom admin codes for your models.
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/contrib/admin/#modeladmin-options

So, if you don't have any custom values for your `ModelAdmin`, then just put `admin.site.register(Question, SummernoteModelAdmin)` without own class declaration.

Answer (score 0):

All I needed to do was add the following to my admin.py script:

```
from django_summernote.admin import SummernoteModelAdmin

class QuestionAdmin(SummernoteModelAdmin):
    pass  # you can add more overrides to the Admin Form but this is all that is needed for overriding the Textfield

admin.site.register(Question, QuestionAdmin)
```

This will override the Admin form to add Summernote in place of the Textfields and register the new Admin form.  I was missing adding QuestionAdmin to the admin.site.register command.

Comment: How to customize the toolbar of summernote? I just need the link button.